# tableHeaderView - layoutSubviews and initWithFrame

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a custom UITableViewHeaderFooterView class and an xib for it. There is a label in this xib which is connected to the custom class using an outlet. This custom class is being used as the tableHeaderView for a table view in a view controller.

I am able to show the header view with required dimensions but the label in the header is not showing any value.

In view controller's viewDidLoad.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
  ..
  DashboardHeaderView* headerView = [[DashboardHeaderView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 180) headerText:@"XYX"];
  self.alertsTableView.tableHeaderView = headerView; 
}
```

In DashboardHeaderView which is a subclass of UITableViewHeaderFooterView.

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame headerText:(NSString *)headerText {
   if (self = [super initWithFrame:frame]) {
      self.headerText = headerText;

      NSArray* objects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"DashboardHeaderView"
                                                     owner:self
                                                   options:nil];
      UIView *nibView = [objects firstObject];
      UIView *contentView = self.contentView;
      contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
      CGSize contentViewSize = contentView.frame.size;
      nibView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, contentViewSize.width, contentViewSize.height);

      [contentView addSubview:nibView];        
  }    
  return self;   
}        

- (void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];
    self.headerLabel.text = self.headerText;
}
```

If I put some log messages in initWithFrame:headerText: and layoutSubviews, I can see that the self of both is pointing to different addresses and hence in layoutSubviews, self.headerText is always nil.

```
layoutSubviews
<DashboardHeaderView: 0x7ff862cf1a90; baseClass = UITableViewHeaderFooterView; frame = (0 0; 320 180); text = ''; opaque = NO; autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x7ff861634e30>>

initWithFrame
<DashboardHeaderView: 0x7ff862cf05e0; baseClass = UITableViewHeaderFooterView; frame = (0 0; 320 180); text = ''; layer = <CALayer: 0x7ff8616d13f0>>

layoutSubviews
<DashboardHeaderView: 0x7ff862cf1a90; baseClass = UITableViewHeaderFooterView; frame = (0 0; 290 180); text = ''; opaque = NO; autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x7ff861634e30>>

layoutSubviews
<DashboardHeaderView: 0x7ff862cf05e0; baseClass = UITableViewHeaderFooterView; frame = (0 0; 290 180); text = ''; layer = <CALayer: 0x7ff8616d13f0>>

layoutSubviews
<DashboardHeaderView: 0x7ff862cf05e0; baseClass = UITableViewHeaderFooterView; frame = (0 0; 290 180); text = ''; layer = <CALayer: 0x7ff8616d13f0>>

layoutSubviews
<DashboardHeaderView: 0x7ff862cf1a90; baseClass = UITableViewHeaderFooterView; frame = (0 0; 345 180); text = ''; opaque = NO; autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x7ff861634e30>>

layoutSubviews
<DashboardHeaderView: 0x7ff862cf05e0; baseClass = UITableViewHeaderFooterView; frame = (0 0; 345 180); text = ''; layer = <CALayer: 0x7ff8616d13f0>>

layoutSubviews
<DashboardHeaderView: 0x7ff862cf1a90; baseClass = UITableViewHeaderFooterView; frame = (0 0; 345 180); text = ''; opaque = NO; autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x7ff861634e30>>

layoutSubviews
<DashboardHeaderView: 0x7ff862cf05e0; baseClass = UITableViewHeaderFooterView; frame = (0 0; 345 180); text = ''; layer = <CALayer: 0x7ff8616d13f0>>
```

If you look at above logs, why do we have two different addresses - 0x7ff862cf1a90 and 0x7ff862cf05e0.

Answer (score 0):

[UIView Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/) says:

> layoutSubviews - Implement this method if you need more precise
>   control over the layout of your subviews than either the constraint or
>   autoresizing behaviors provide.

You are setting a value of an UILabel inside the `layoutSubviews` method, that is intended only for resizing operations.

I suggest you to move the `self.headerLabel.text = self.headerText` instruction into the `initWithFrame:headerText:` method and perform other operations like resizing or changing constraints into the `layoutSubviews` method.

In this way it works fine!
[image]